# How to call a function in "ng-src"

Tags: angularjs

I need to be able to call a function in order to run code to dynamically retrieve the source of an image. The following code snippet shows an example of what I want:

```
<!-- "myFunction" exists in the current scope -->
<img ng-src="myFunction()" />
```

I'm sure this has to be simple but I just can't find anything in the [ng-src documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)! Anyone else ever hit this?

Thanks in advance!

**The Directive (Example based on answers)**

Others recommended a directive. I can't post client code so I wrote a short example of what that would could look like in plunker ([see here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hTSa13jYde2bfUOEHWC6?p=preview)). The core directive itself is:

```
app.directive("imageSource", function (){
  return { link: function (scope, element, attrs){
      element.attr("src", scope.imageUrlArray[attrs.imageSource]);
    }
  };
});
```

I know that what I have here as an example could probably just be done with the ng-repeat using the variable in an ng-src but it serves as an example of what a directive *would* look like if one were necessary.

Comment: If you want to call a function like this you should really write a new [Directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: @Liam I've written many directives before. Any particular reason this is a case for a directive vs just calling the function to get the url directly?

Comment: `ng-src` **is** a directive, right. Your calling a directive to call a function. Why? Why not simply write a custom directive that returns what myfunction does. It'd be a whole lot neater.

Comment: @Liam Got it! I'll definitely consider doing that. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: If you have an answer, you should actually post an answer, not put the answer in the question. Good work BTW. I think we've come to the same conclusion, roughly!

Comment: @Liam Noted! Strictly speaking I figured that wasn't an answer to my original question but was sort of just a useful "side bar". In the future though - I'll post as an answer instead!

Answer (score 92, accepted):

```
<img ng-src="{{myFunction()}}" />
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wktwL/5/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I should have guessed at this but since this isn't my normal pattern, I hadn't tried this before.

Comment: I would like to see a better solution using custom directive as @Liam suggested.

Comment: I'll write that fast in JSFiddle and will amend my question to include that for those who have the same sort of issue in the future. Watch for that soon (if you care)!

Comment: I thought this'd be straight forward, but as is often the case with angular (for me anyway) I'm struggling. I'll have a play when I have more time and try and post something.

Comment: I have tested this method and found out that it is not suitable for calling $http service or any other function because, angularjs continues to run the function as a loop

Comment: Yes the answer is correct, but It loops way too many times. (if under a ng- repeat ) This is not advisable.

Answer (score 5):

Right, got there in the end:

### JavaScript:

```
 angular.module('MyApp', [])
    .controller('Ctrl2', function($scope) {
    })
    .directive('mySrc', function() {
        return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ( scope, elem, attrs ) {
             //replace test with whatever myFunction() does
             elem.attr('src', 'test1');
        }
      };
    });
```

### HTML:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
      <img my-src />
  </div>
</div>
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43czG/1/)

Comment: What about passing myFunction as an argument to the directive?

Comment: do this method maintain angular's double data binding?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to pass myFunction as an argument to the custom directive? That way, we decouple the two, and can easily change which function to pass in in the future.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app='testApp'>
    <div ng-controller='TestCtrl'>
        <img my-src callback='myFunction()' />
    </div>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module('testApp', [])
.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myFunction = function() {
        return 'http://nodejs.org/images/roadshow-promo.png';
    }
})
.directive('mySrc', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            callback: '&'
        },
        link: function ( scope, elem, attrs ) {
            elem.attr('src', scope.callback());
        }
    };
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GLS2a/

Comment: But by doing this your effectively putting the logic (myFunction) into the view, when the logic should exist in the controller (separation of concerns). I also don't see how this is better than the solution CodeHater provided. It's the same thing, but wrapped in a slightly different way

Comment: How is your directive different to `ng-src`?