# function in ng-src executed multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a small list and want to execute a function for each list item. But this function gets executed multiple times and I don't know why.

HTML:

```
  <body  ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    <div>
        <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
          <li>{{item.name}}<img ng-src="{{test()}}"></li>
        </ul>
        {{counter}}
    </div>
  </body>
```

Angular:

```
$scope.items = [
{name: 'foo', },
{name: 'bar', },
{name: 'baz', }
];
var counter= 0;
$scope.test= function(){
$scope.counter=counter++;
console.log("Executed");
}
```

Why is the function text executed multiple times?
 Also see this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/kxJZHCmFs4POd3SVtGZ8

Answer (score 3):

This is an expected behavior. Whenever an interpolation expression `{{}}` is met in html template there is a watch created to track changes in that expression. During a `$digest` cycle the expression can be evaluated dozens of times.
Never use function calls in interpolation expressions. Only reference properties defined in `$scope`. In your case it should be something like

```
$scope.testValue = $scope.test();

{{testValue}}
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly fine. But, what if we have to pass parameters?

Comment: @ChandrasekarG pass them in controller code, '$scope.test(params);'

Comment: What if, we use it at multiple places in HTML each with different parameters. Passing the params in the above way will work only if the params value is same.

Comment: @ChandrasekarG, the only solution I see is to evaluate once and store in a variable that should be referenced by expression in curly braces. I think that the neatest solution would be to implement a directive like [here (see edited question)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225609/how-to-call-a-function-in-ng-src)