# Passing scope parameters to a Custom Directive as ng-src is being called repeatedly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

My current implementation is shown below which is working but as the getImage method is inside expressions its being called repeatedly when any text change or data is entered on the page

HTML

```
        <div ng-repeat="product in pageData.products">
           <div>
            <img style="width:60px;" ng-src={{getImage(product)}} />
          </div>              
        </div>
```

JS:

```
    $scope.getImage = function(product)
{
       var image = Utils.getLocalStorageEntityByIdFromList(product.ID,"ProductID", "images");
       if(image) return image.Data;
        else return "";
};
```

I am trying put getImage method inside a .directive as most posts are suggesting and pass product as parameter inside the directive. 
Post link
[How to call a function in "ng-src"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225609/how-to-call-a-function-in-ng-src)

I am new to AngularJS, any help in putting the getImage method in a directive where the product parameter can be passed I will be really thankful.

Something along these lines shown below..

JS:

```
 angular.module('MyApp', [])
    .controller('Ctrl2', function($scope) {
    })
    .directive('mySrc', function() {
        return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ( scope, elem, attrs ) {
             var image = Utils.getLocalStorageEntityByIdFromList(product.ID,"ProductID", "images");
             elem.attr('src', image.Data);
        }
      };
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
   <div ng-repeat="product in pageData.products">
     <div><img my-src="product" /><div>      
   </div>
</div>
```

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: update your post with this method and **getLocalStorageEntityByIdFromList** notify me

Comment: Hi Aravid, thanks for looking into it. Sorry I didn't understand what you meant, the second piece of JS code with .directive is currently not working thats what i'm not sure about..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid multiple calls to a function in an AngularJS Expression, use [one-time binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding):

```
<div ng-repeat="product in pageData.products">
   <div>
    <!-- REPLACE This
    <img style="width:60px;" ng-src={{getImage(product)}} />
    -->
    <!-- WITH One time binding -->
    <img style="width:60px;" ng-src={{::getImage(product)}} />
  </div>              
</div>
```

One-time bindings are especially useful in `ng-repeat` contents because they significantly reduce the number of active watchers.

From the Docs:

> ### One-time binding
>
> An expression that starts with `::` is considered a one-time expression. One-time expressions will stop recalculating once they are stable, which happens after the first digest if the expression result is a non-undefined value (see value stabilization algorithm below).

-- [AngularJS Developer Guide -- Expressions -- One-time Binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding)

Comment: Thank you very much georgeawg, One-Time binding worked pefectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

ng-src actually uses attr.$observe.  That may not be necessary in your specific case.

It seems like it would be possible to only pass the product id, since that is all that is used to get the image URL.  I might try the following as a starting point for your custom directive.

**HTML**

```
<div><img my-src="product.ID" /><div>
```

**JS**

```
//in your new custom directive my-src
scope : {id:'=mySrc'},
link: function ( scope, elem, attrs ) {
    var image = Utils.getLocalStorageEntityByIdFromList(scope.id,"ProductID", "images");
    attrs.$set('src',image.Data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the above answer, This is exactly what I needed but i haven't tried this out, as the one-time binding solution worked for me. Many thanks for your time